# Insert blank page after each record in Crystal Report

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that can show one or more (depending on the input) records. Each record can have one or more pages. I need to insert a blank page after every record (not just every record on a page, also a blank page after each record).

I've tried checking `New Page Before` / `New Page After` but all I managed to get was duplicate entries or a blank page at the end of the report (I need one after every record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it as:

- Split your *Details* section or your *Group Footer*, after which you want a blank page, into two sub-sections e.g. `Details a`, `Details b` or `Group Footer a`, `Group Footer b`.
- To insert a sub-section: open *Section Expert*, select *Details* or *Group Footer* and then click on *Insert* button.
- Enable / check `New Page After` option of both of theses sub-sections in *Section Expert*
- Ensure that `Suppress Blank Section` is **unchecked**
- If required, to disable insert blank page at the end of the report set suppression formula in `New Page After` as `Not OnLastRecord`

**Update:** To suppress header and footer information on blank page

- Create two *Formula Fields*, `ShowHF` and `HideHF`
- Set value of `ShowHF` as:

  ```
  WhilePrintingRecords;
  numberVar ShowInfo := 1;
  ```
- Set value of `HideHF` as:

  ```
  WhilePrintingRecords;
  numberVar ShowInfo := 0;
  ```
- Place `ShowHF` in `Details a` sub-section and `HideHF` in `Details b` sub-section and suppress both `ShowHF` and `HideHF`
- Set the suppression formula for *Page Header* and *Page Footer* as:

  ```
  numberVar ShowInfo = 0;
  ```

Comment: Your method adds a new page after each record, but the page contains header and footer information (I want a blank page). I'm thinking of suppressing the header and the footer for the last page on the record. I can use `PageNumber = TotalPageCount` to determine if I am on the last page of the report, but I don't know how to determine if I am on the last page of the current record.

Comment: Check update for suppressing header and footer information.